# find level of element in json object using recursive function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a recursive function as shown below. I hav used it to convert tree elements into json object. I have converted it into multilevel object. I am unable to find in which level the elements lie. How can I find the level of the elements in the object? Level count refers to the level in below code.

```
var levelCount = 1;
    var levelText;
    var convertTreeObjToJson = function (treeObj) {

        return $.map(treeObj, function (n, i) {
            var tempTitle;
            var tempToolTip;
            levelCount = levelCount + 1;
            levelText = "level_" + levelCount;
            debugger;
            treeDataStorageJson.map(function (mindmapdata) {
                if (mindmapdata.title == n.text) {
                    tempTitle = mindmapdata.title;
                    tempToolTip = mindmapdata.tooltip;
                }
            });
            if (tempToolTip == "") {
                var result = { title: tempTitle };
            }
            else {
                var result = { toolTip: tempToolTip, title: tempTitle };
            }
            if (n.hasChildren){

                result[levelText] = convertTreeObjToJson(n.children.view());
            }
            return result;
        }); 
    };
```

Here is sample json object

```
{
    "level_1": {
        "title": "Item 1",
        "level_2": [
            {
                "toolTip": "fdsa",
                "title": "Item 2",
                "level_3": [
                    {
                        "toolTip": "fdsaf",
                        "title": "Item 3",
                        "level_4": [
                            {
                                "toolTip": "fdsa",
                                "title": "Item 5"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "toolTip": "fdsa",
                        "title": "Item 4"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "toolTip": "dsaf",
                "title": "Item 6",
                "level_3": [
                    {
                        "toolTip": "dsaf",
                        "title": "Item 7"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "toolTip": "dsfa",
                "title": "Item 8"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: its hard to understand your code, but please give sample of source tree element and give which type of json you need.

Comment: I am using kendo treeview. the function above is recursive which converts tree element to object but I need to find level of the elements also thats why I tried to use counter but in recursive function it has become quit tricky. I will provide sample json output but the level is not correct using above function.